# Assignment in Programming language for microcontroller

Tags: programming-languages, microcontroller

If my left hand side operator is BYTE type and I am assigning 560(something more than 256) what will be assigned to left hand side operator?

```
DECLARE X BYTE;

X= 560;

OUTPUT OF X?
```

I know what happens in C, I need answers for PL/M. 
If anybody knows how to practice PL/M code, that will be also useful.

thanks

Comment: Why are you using this language?

Comment: this language used in our project.

Comment: @DeepakRout Here's a link for Compiler: http://vetusware.com/download/Intel%20PLM-86%20Compiler%20V2.7%20_DOS%20Version_%202.7/?id=7751

Comment: Do you have an actual device or emulator you can program after you write your code? If so, why not just run an experiment to find out for yourself?

Comment: @ScottLawson i don't have actual device access

Comment: @Swanand thanks, the link u have provided has only 32 bit compiler. i am using 64 bit OS. can u send me link for 64 bit. someone commented tool is not valid one.

Comment: @DeepakRout I found this in Wikipedia article... Search on internet and you might find it!

Comment: No one uses PL/M anymore unless they're bound to legacy systems and can't upgrade for some reason. A 64-bit compiler probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @ScottLawson yes, it is legacy software. flight warning system. a big project like this will be very costlier to change to different language.

Comment: @DeepakRout Indeed that would be expensive. What's keeping you from programming your system with these statements and checking the output yourself? If there's some kind of console/screen, you can print the result. If you at least have an LED or a speaker that can produce beeps, you can work out some kind of code for yourself that can output the result. I've used LEDs to blink binary patterns from microcontrollers before. Even if you got the answer here on SO, wouldn't you want to verify it?

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, consider moving this question over to [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). You might have better luck since they're more electronics oriented.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will complain that you are trying to write word value to a byte.